# Str is already defined as a global variable

Tags: python, string, variables, global

I noticed something really strange while working with functions. It looks like the variable name 'str' is already defined as a global variable. Take a look:

```
def Example(x):
   str = input()
   return str

print (Example(str))
#When typing 'Hello!' Output --> Hello!
```

The variable str is defined in the function Example. So why is there no NameError: name 'str' is not defined?

When I call the variable x or something else ( In this case 'bar'):

```
def Example(x):
   bar = input()
   return bar

print (Example(bar))
#Output: NameError: name 'bar'is not defined
```

Why does a variable with the name 'str' act as a global variable?

Comment: Because `str` is a type in Python

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html for details about `str`. As for the question itself, I'd recommend a *Python* beginner's tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python, str() is the string constructor. It is used to cast an object to a string.

You can use it locally, but it will override the access to the function. You will not be able to use str() anymore.

for reference:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str

> class str(object='')
>
> Return a string containing a nicely printable representation of an
>   object. For strings, this returns the string itself. The difference
>   with repr(object) is that str(object) does not always attempt to
>   return a string that is acceptable to eval(); its goal is to return a
>   printable string. If no argument is given, returns the empty string,
>   ''.

For general knowledge purpose, you can get back you constructor if you delete your variable. For example:

```
test = 1
str(test)
>>>'1'

str = 2
str(test)
>>>TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

del str

str(test)
>>>'1'
```

Comment: Minor point, but `str()` is not a function for casting. It's a constructor for a `str` object.

Comment: Thanks! using the str() function does not work anymore indeed (UnboundLocalError). I know now that you should never give variables names like variable types. Like float, int etc.

Comment: Class override yup.

Comment: Anymore unless you `del str`. The original is still there :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As the op is learning, I added it to the answer with an example. For general knowledge

Answer (score 2):

The reason this fails:

```
def Example(x):
   bar = input()
   return bar

print (Example(bar))
#Output: NameError: name 'bar'is not defined
```

Is because you're attempting to pass the variable `bar` to the `Example()` method, but `bar` was never defined anywhere prior to the call.

I'm not really sure what it is you want to accomplish with this method anyhow, since you pass a variable but don't use it at all.

**Comment Response:**

`str` is not a built-in function (albeit listed on the [page](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-str)), but rather it is the constructor for the built-in type [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str). To show that you are simply reassigning the method associated with the keyword (not necessarily reserved, but it is a keyword nonetheless), consider the following:

```
>>> str
<class 'str'>
>>> abs
<built-in function abs>
>>> str = abs
>>> str
<built-in function abs>
```

Thus you've essentially overwritten the assignment to the `str` class constructor. I used `abs` in this example, but the same applies (with a twist) for `input`:

```
>>> str
<class 'str'>
>>> input
<built-in function input>
>>> str = input
>>> str
<built-in function input>
>>> str = input()
hello world
>>> str
'hello world'
```

Difference here is you assign a string (of type `str`) to the keyword `str`. So you can never use `str(10)` to get `'10'` because that would now be like calling `hello world(10)` which fails.

Comment: My point was to show difference between outputs of a variable named 'str' and for example 'bar'. I get why varname = 'bar' results in an exception.

Comment: @HugodeHeer Its because you are remapping the function associated with that reserved word.

Comment: It's not exactly a reserved word, or you would get a syntax error on assignment. Try `for=0`. `str`is a built-in function. Builtins are the last namespace searched (after the global).

Comment: My comment above was more for @HugodeHeer, but forgot to mention him.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a keyword as a variable name, by convention a single trailing underscore is used to avoid conflicts with Python keywords, like so:

```
single_trailing_underscore_
```

Cf. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Codes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: Just to complement, an isolated underscore  `_` is sometimes used when you don't care about a returned value, usually when unpacking a tuple with multiple values.